# magento 2 crash after set to Client side less compilation

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy, less-compilation

i'm working on magento 2.2.2 .after i set client side less compilation mod (default value is server side compilation mod can be accessed via STORES > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer > Front-end development workflow > Server side less compilation) magento crashed.
i got this error when refresh home page see the following screenshot
[image]

and when i run php magento setup:static-content:deploy -f i got the following errors see the following screen shot 
[image]

can anyone help me ?!

Comment: I am having an issue after setting out the client side less compilation. It says less files (_extend.less, _variables.less) wasn't found (403) forbidden. do you know if this is also releated to your issue? If yes could you tell me the solution for this? Thankyou